# Any tool available for incremental redeployment or Hotcode replacement in java

Tags: glassfish

I am using glassFish server and whenver there is any java code change in one or two files,I need to build an ear of the whole project by Ant tool and redeploy it on Glassfish server.It takes a long time for deploy and redeploy even for smaller changes in one or two files.Is there any way out or any tool available with which my code change will automatically get reflected in glassfish server like in case of hot code replacement and there would be no chnage of undeploying and deploying again and again.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762567/when-a-class-file-change-can-i-make-the-glassfish-server-not-restart-but-still-r/5765222#5765222) has some pointers to info on directory deployment and the redeploy command.

Use directory deployment to eliminate the need to create an EAR file.  Use  some of the advanced options of the redeploy command to prevent the losing your session state.

Other folks are likely to chime in with pointers to JRebel...

You can also start the server under a debugger and use the ability to apply limited 'hot fixes' to your Java code that is part of JPDA.